# MySql getting conditional records using if else in where clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my site i have to store two types of delivery dates contract delivery date and adjusted delivery date for  orders.Basically contract date is delivery date of productes at the time of order taken .and adjusted date is adjusteants in date that can be less or grater then contract date

Table is like below:

```
id   product_name  condeldat adjdeldate
----------------------------------------
1     drilling      2011-05    2012-01
2     lathe         2012-06
```

I have to check if any product have adjusted date then pick adjusted date else contract date

Done with below query :

```
select id,
       product_name,
       if(adjdeldat is not NULL, adjdeldat, condeldat) as delivery_date     
 from orders
```

Above query works fine but I have to get products with any delivery date(if(adjdelcat is not NULL,adjdeldat,condetdat)) > lastyear (for now it will be 2011).So my question is how to apply same if condition in where clause ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make conditions equivalent to `if else` using `AND`, `OR`

Try below:

```
SELECT id,product_name,if(adjdeldat is not NULL,adjdeldat,condeldat) as delivery_date 
FROM orders  
WHERE ((adjdeldat is NULL and left(condeldat) > 2011) OR left(adjdeldat) > 2011)
```

for dynamically getting last year you may use:

```
(left(curdate(),4)-1) in place of 2011
```

Comment: Really you have good understanding. This works exactly what i wants. Thank you very much KingFisher

Answer (score 0):

use Having expression:

```
 select id, product_name,
 if(adjdeldat is not NULL, adjdeldat, condeldat) as delivery_date     
 from orders  HAVING delivery_date BETWEEN 'beginDate' AND 'endDate'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a derived table/inline view:

```
SELECT x.id, x.product_name, x.delivery_date  
  FROM (SELECT o.id, o.product_name, IFNULL(o.adjdeldat, o.condeldat) AS delivery_date
          FROM ORDERS o) x
 WHERE x.delivery_date BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-12-31'
```

- You could replace IFNULL with the ANSI `COALESCE`, or CASE statement
- Always compare values with the same data type, or your query can't use an index if one exists
- depending on the operation, the optimizer might use predicate pushing (unlikely in this case) to push the outer query's filtering into the inner query